# Someone is systematically down-voting my old questions and the abuse algorithm is not catching it

Tags: support, down-votes, abuse

I got in to a bit of a argument with another user a few weeks ago. Ever since then every few days I get a down-vote on one of my old questions that has not been touched in months or years. Also it is not like these are bad questions either, they all had a rep of 7 or more and none of them had a existing down-vote except one, but that one had a +11 on it by the time this started happening.

Questions being downvoted:

- [How to generate a guitar note](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664594/how-to-generate-a-guitar-note) (my very first SO question from 2.5 years ago)
- [Parallel.ForEach can cause a "Out Of Memory" exception if working with a enumerable with a large object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6977218/parallel-foreach-can-cause-a-out-of-memory-exception-if-working-with-a-enumera)
- [How do I protect OAuth keys from a user decompiling my project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7623335/how-do-i-protect-oauth-keys-from-a-user-decompileing-my-project) (this had the existing down-vote)
- [How do user annotations work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7706880/how-do-user-annotations-work)
- [Do stored procedures lock tables/rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841309/do-stored-procedures-lock-tables-rows)
- [Serializing a Nullable<DateTime> in to XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2074240/serializing-a-nullabledatetime-in-to-xml)
- [What to do when you can not save a password as a hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2273496/what-to-do-when-you-can-not-save-a-password-as-a-hash)

---

This is the argument that I think started it all, there is no way for me to tell who is doing this, but I have a strong suspicion that it is this user.

- [Best way to store passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8617593/80274)

Comment: If it's only 7 questions over a long period of time (more than one day), the voter fraud script is probably not going to catch it.  If a single user is downvoting your questions, I can message them and tell them to stop.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I recently got hit with down votes (on SO site) across multiple questions on the same day within 2min of each vote and I tried to report it with flags but nothing was done about it or I wasn't contacted so is there any chance you can please look into it? (Happened on Jan 21 at 16:26/28/30)